# Evaluate the gradient and Hessian of f(x).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

Consider the function
$f(x) = a^T xb^T x$,
where $a, x, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Evaluate the gradient and Hessian of $f(x)$.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: yes, i have tried with respect to gradient , want to derive the hessian of f(x). will be helpful, if the answer is in detail which helps me in understanding the concept

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial a^\top x b^\top x}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial x^\top a b^\top x}{\partial x} = (ab^\top + ba^\top)x $$
Taking another derivative, for the Hessian we get:
$$\frac{\partial ~(ab^\top + ba^\top)x}{\partial x} =  ab^\top + ba^\top $$